# Using ADAL With .NET Core RC2 and OnPremise Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add authentication to a .NET Core RC2 MVC 6 Web Application. Our company does have an AD endpoint that we can use for authentication against the directory. It was my understanding that the endpoint can be hit using the ADAL library, but everything I've seen using that ADAL library is using Azure, which we do not have set up.

How would I go about integrating ADAL into my web app, knowing that Azure is (at the moment) not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can't. You need to wait for ADFS 2016, which supports OpenID connect

You could use the generic OAuth2 pieces and configure ADFS for OAuth, but it's not as fully featured - http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html

Comment: Okay, then how would I go about authenticating against an on-premise AD without using ADAL? It looks like things are REALLY being pushed to Azure, which as I mentioned before is not yet an option.

Comment: If all the sites are internal good old Windows auth will work. Or you do as I suggested above with oauth or upgrade your ADFS servers to a 2016 beta.